# Static pages (.html) vs ASP.NET pages (.aspx)

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, performance

we are going to develop a media website where we will show current news.

For that we have 2 strategies:

1. Create window service in C# which will generate static (.html) pages for website (with updated news) as there will be only images and text (no postback or server-side event required) on website and then service will upload affected pages on server.
2. Create application in ASP.NET (.NET Framework 4.0) and use output caching for few minutes in it (as news updates in every 2-3 minutes).

Please suggest which one from above will be more preferable from performance (or other) point of view in my situation.

Please also suggest if any other strategy may provide me better solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Making static pages will also prevents user to wait until new page is generated on server,so there is no way,only html can understand either new page or itself is generated again.This will cause user to make an interaction with the page (refresh) to find new results,so the cycle ends.You cannot expect user to know when content is changed.

As long as the content is dynamic in time interval,you should prefer asp.net solution with AJAX requests.You can make this with single page.

DO NOT FORGET that either developing via HTML or aspx or any kind will display your results in HTML output,so unless your page shall use any server content,try asp.net dynamically.

I can also assist code,please verify the specs.

Best Regards

Comment: thanks a lot for quick reply. Its our requirement that user should refresh page to get updated news as we want pageviews on our advertisements.

Comment: we have a CMS from which our news editors will enter news and using website we will show that content.

Comment: We have web farming for servers, a load-balancer server have facility to cache the html output of all servers.

Comment: Putting advertisement into page is whole different thing than defining cycle of the page itself.Your specs is more than enough to contain server requirements.What do you need exactly at this point ?

Comment: as you suggested me asp.net dynamic data. i am looking for some good articles for it.. (reading some, but please provide if you have some good links)

Comment: Check these links.[asp.net dynamic data](http://www.asp.net/aspnet-in-net-35-sp1/videos/getting-started-with-dynamic-data) and [dynamic data](http://mattberseth.com/blog/2008/08/aspnet_dynamic_data_simple_5_t.html)

Answer (score 0):

Second one will be nice method

Problem with the first method:

1. HTML page want to be created each time
2. Created HTML pages what to be deleted or overwritten each time
3. Whole page want to be recreated (by using AJAX update can be done faster)

so comparatively second one is the right method.